# Is it well-defined to take reference of an R-value reference

Tags: c++

In a function taking an R-value reference, is it well-defined if we take its reference?  For example:

```
void foo(int &&i) {
    cout << &i << endl;
}
int main() {
    int i = 1;
    cout << &i << endl;
    foo(std::move(i));
    return 0;
}
```

Both `cout` print the same value, but is it well-defined or undefined?

Or like this:

```
void foo(int &&i) {
    cout << &i << endl;
}
int main() {
    foo(1);
    return 0;
}
```

`cout` prints some address, but is it valid (not pointing any existing object) or just random value?

Comment: Yes, it's okay. R-value reference variable is l-value.

Comment: Note, your aren't taking the reference, you're taking the address. In when not used in a type `&` is the "address of operator" not a reference